# Change the color of Status bar items (symbols) to black

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Can I give black color for the status bar items? Because I need to change the background color to white as shown below.Then I can't see the status bar items hence those are also white color.Any help?

**Note:** I'm testing this on `Android` device (6.0).

```
this.statusBar.styleDefault();
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#fff");//white
```

*Now (i.e. White items):*

[image]

*I need like this(i.e. Black items):*

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/brightness": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-brightness": "^0.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.4.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.8",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.0.29",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-brightness": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "60",
        "APP_NAME": "app"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `styleLightContent()`?

Comment: No difference.According to the doc, I think it is wrong too `Use the lightContent statusbar (light text, for dark backgrounds).`. @awmleer

Comment: Ohhh...Sorry about my mistake. I also noticed that there is a note in the documentation: `you must call StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false) to enable color changing`.

Comment: It is for `iOS` no? I'm testing on `Android`. @awmleer

Comment: Sorry...I thought you were debugging on an iOS device since it's a iPhone screenshot...This problem seems beyond my ability... Maybe you can add a `cordova` tag so that more people can see this post? (Sorry I couldn't offer much help)

Comment: it may be a silly suggestion, but what happens if you use the color but with the 6 digits? like this: `this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#ffffff"); //white`

Comment: Also please notice that the `backgroundColorByHexString` method is only supported in Android 5+ [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#statusbarbackgroundcolorbyhexstring)

Comment: No difference.Yes My device is `Android 6.0` @sebaferreras

Comment: Here the problem is not on `backgroundColorByHexString`.It is working fine.But `this.statusBar.styleDefault();` is not working.@sebaferreras

Comment: That makes sense. `styleDefault` is only compatible with ios and windows phone: [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#statusbarstyledefault). :(

Comment: Oh.. That is very useful info.Hope we cannot change items color then on Android no? @sebaferreras

Comment: I think you can only change the background color, but I guess the font color will be set based on that... I've changed the status bar background color several times, using a dark color, and the font color was set to white...

Comment: Hmm..Can you please put that as an answer? Thanks. @sebaferreras

Comment: done :) Sorry for not being so helpful this time...

Comment: This is very helpful.Because I can tell about this to my client :) Thanks. @sebaferreras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but `styleDefault` is only available on ios and windows phone ([docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/#statusbarstyledefault))

```
StatusBar.styleDefault
Use the default statusbar (dark text, for light backgrounds).

Supported Platforms
_ iOS
_ Windows Phone 7
_ Windows Phone 8
_ Windows Phone 8.1
```

That being said, I think you can only change the **background** color, but I guess the **font** color will be set based on that... I've changed the status bar background color several times, using a dark color, and the font color was set to white automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In xml (theme attribute):

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">
```

Or programmatically:

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.some_view); if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
```

someView.setSystemUiVisibility(someView.getSystemUiVisibility() |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}

Sorry writing it on mobile it's hard to put code into these code fields there...

Comment: This is not a native Android app.This is hybrid Ionic app.Hope this is not working with Ionic.Thanks.