# Ionic 3 Android app's status bar Text color to Dark or Black

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I need to change the Status bar text color to dark (or black).But [**it is not supported on Cordova plugin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738807/1077309).But I have seen where there is a method on Android native device as shown below.Can we do the same on Ionic 3 app too?

**[Refernce:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33508579/1077309)**

```
<style name="statusBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried this plugin ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/
Then you check which platform you are in app.component.ts and you set the style you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#1f2933');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding the color of your DOM element to a variable and change that.

OR

You could make two different DOM elements, one of each color and decide which one is shown by using *ngIf